# Using printf to display an extracted string through grep and to be use as user input in a script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, printf

Good day,

This is kinda lenghty, Im hoping for the kind help of anybody who can support me on this simple problem (to others) but taking me almost forever to figure out.
I have this file (EOL.txt) which consists of the following sample lists:

```
   35 - 5976

   36 - 5976C0

   53 - 5976C2

   64 - 5976D0

   69 - 43593

   72 - 43593C0
```

Im using the following commands to extract the leftmost figure since this correspond to a routine number of another script:

```
grep 5976C2 EOL.txt | head -n1 | cut -d- -f1
```

After I acquired that number, I will input that along with the other data on another script (N.csh-syntax as follows) that will execute another one (Test.csh):

```
$./N.csh 53 XXXX.XX "01 02 03"

N.csh --> printf "$1\n$2\n$3\nYYYY\n1\nN\n" | /export/home/Script/Test.csh
```

What I want to do now is to incorporate the grep command to N.csh so that I wont have to do that separately. It should look like this:

```
$./N.csh 5976C2 XXXX.XX "01 02 03"
```

I tried the following commands but its not working.

```
grep $1 EOL.txt | head -n1 | cut -d- -f1 >> A ; set B=`cat A` ; printf %s "$B\n$2\n$3\n82869\n1\nN\n"
```

Im new to this stuff, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in the file N.csh:

```
set mynumber = `grep $1 EOL.txt | head -n1 | cut -d- -f1`
printf "$mynumber\n$2\n$3\n...
```

and then invoke N.csh like
    ./N.csh 5976C2 XXXX.XX "01 02 03"

Note that after `set mynumber =`, in the first line, there is a "backtick" - a reversed single quote. The shell executes the commands delimited by two backticks, takes the output, and puts it back in place of the original contents, so the first line turns into `set mynumber = 53`.

Comment: Hi linuxfan, thanks for checking this.. i tried your solution but it's not displaying the value of mynumber:

Comment: @Mike did you cut'n'paste? There was a typo mynumber->mynumver... I edited just now. Also, put an "echo $mynumber" just after "set mynumber", to check what is happening.

Comment: yeah I saw that typo and I corrected it, still no value shown. i used printf to display the value of mynumber

Comment: Put `#!/bin/csh` as first line in your file! Everything was working, but as you said, it didn't when running N.csh. It was because the script was executed by bash!

Comment: I removed the set command and instead used A=`grep $1 EOL.txt | head -n1 | cut -d- -f1`
printf "$A\n$2\n$3\n82869\n1\nN\n" and its displaying the inputs I listed but when I pipped it to Test.csh its now prompting syntax error. Not sure if $A is really being passed as an input to the script

Comment: If the script is executed by CSH, `set A = ...` is correct; if executed by BASH or other bourne shell, `A=...` is correct instead. Try to understand which shell is used - I assumed CSH because your script name ends with `.csh`.

Comment: my shell is csh  as it showed /usr/bin/csh when echoed. Anyway, I think I find a way to make it work now, I added csh infront of the Test.csh and it did the trick. Really appreciate the time and patience you gave for this, thanks a lot, hope you reach out to more newbies like me, God bless.